# RollingRandomAccessFile - How to put the date into the current log¿?

Tags: java, log4j2

Hola como puedo mostrar la fecha en el log actual.

```
    <RollingRandomAccessFile name="Error" 
        fileName="${ruta}/ERR/${nombre}_${sys:APP}_%d{yyMMdd}.log"
        filePattern="${ruta}/ERR/${nombre}_${sys:APP}_%d{yyMMdd}_%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false" bufferSize="128">
        <PatternLayout>     
            <pattern>${a}|${app}_%d{yyMMdd}|%m%n</pattern>
        </PatternLayout>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB"/>
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="99" />
    </RollingRandomAccessFile>
```

De esta forma se escribe en el log rotado pero no el actual.

Thanks.

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflo en **Español** , por favor para que tu pregunta no sea cerrada traduce tu pregunta al idioma de la web. Un saludo :)

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres poner la fecha en el actual? En mi experiencia es muy cómodo saber que el fichero de log actual se llama siempre igual, con lo que puedes automatizar el acceder a él sin preocuparte de qué día es hoy. Además visualmente es fácil verlo en una lista de ficheros porque el nombre es más corto que el de todos los logs anteriores.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder. El hecho de querer poner la fecha es por comodidad.

De todas formas he conseguido mostrar de esta forma para futuras necesidades.

Comment: Si has encontrado una solución, ponla como respuesta, por favor :)

Answer (score 2):

Encontré esta solución para mostrar la fecha en el `fileName` -> `${date:yyMMdd}`.

```
<RollingRandomAccessFile name="Error" 
     fileName="${ruta}/ERR/${nombre}_${sys:APP}_${date:yyMMdd}.log
    filePattern="${ruta}/ERR/${nombre}_${sys:APP}_%d{yyMMdd}_%i.log.gz" immediateFlush="false" bufferSize="128">
    <PatternLayout>     
        <pattern>${a}|${app}_%d{yyMMdd}|%m%n</pattern>
    </PatternLayout>
    <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="2 MB"/>
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="99" />
</RollingRandomAccessFile>
```